# Server-side redirect to angular SPA view

Tags: angularjs

How do you get a server-side redirect to go to a certain view in an angular app? I am guessing it has something to do with the redirect not triggering the part after the hash, but can this limitation be beat?

### More info

I'm redirecting from an MVC controller to a page with an angular app. I'm using ui-router. The page containing the ui-view gets rendered, but processing stops there. If I refresh twice or go to the URL manually the page works as expected.

The MVC controller is called from a form which posts a file to the server and asynchronously populates a database and redirects when it's finished.

Comment: Can you give me some feedback?, it's pretty sad to invest some time writing a runnable example and having no comments from you.

Comment: I'm really sorry, but I solved my problem and didn't get around to posting anything before I went on vacation. The problem was Batarang (https://github.com/angular/batarang/issues/167). I removed Batarang and the problem went away.

Comment: Oh, that's ok, cheers!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I don't see the problem, you can send a full url with hash and all on the location header and the browser will follow it, just check the response headers for this:

http://web-cf8f140d-22d3-4acd-b7a5-f9fa4e15e094.runnablecodesnippets.com/

What you can't do is getting the hash part directly from the request on the server side.